# Bootstrap tabs disappear after clicking onto another tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, bootstrapping

I've tried CSS tricks to try and keep the tabs to stay appearing, but everything I click a tab - it disappears as soon as I click onto another tab.

I tried moving the JS code around and moving certain CSS attributes to the bottom of the page, beneath the tab code; nothing happens.

Could it be possible that because I have a tab on the header, that it's doing this?

the code and tabs together looks ok, no misspellings.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was an incompatibility with prototype :(

Answer (score 2):

```
     $(document).off('click.tab.data-api');
    $(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $($(this).attr('href'));
        var activate = !tab.hasClass('active');
        $('div.tab-content>div.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
        $('ul.nav.nav-tabs>li.active').removeClass('active');
        if (activate) {
            $(this).tab('show')
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works, but why is this even needed?  Is this a bug in the later versions of BS3?  I've used tabs many times with slightly earlier versions and never seen this issue until now. We are now using 3.3.7.